# How to update nuke.frame() value in NUKE via Python?

Tags: python, nuke

I want to automatically play and stop the sequence in The Foundry NUKE using `if...else` conditional statements. I can easily start playing the sequence but I can't stop it. The problem is a value `nuke.frame()` doesn't update. If someone has any experience on this issue, please help me.

Here's a code:

```
checker = nuke.createNode('CheckerBoard2', 'boxsize 100 centerlinewidth 0')
blur = nuke.createNode('Blur', 'size sin(frame/10)*25', inpanel=False)
merge = nuke.createNode('Merge2', inpanel=False)
wheel = nuke.createNode("ColorWheel", 'rotate frame*10 centerSaturation 1')
merge.connectInput(0, wheel)
nuke.toNode('Merge1').setSelected(True)
nukescripts.connect_selected_to_viewer(0)

for all in nuke.allNodes():
    all.setSelected(True)
_autoplace()

f = nuke.frame(1)

def playBlast():
    if f >= 1 and f <= 99:
        nuke.activeViewer().play(1)
        return        
    else:
        nuke.activeViewer().stop()
        print f

playBlast()
```

Comment: Your code, as many of your edit suggestions on other posts, violates PEP8 because of your use of spaces, which makes it harder to read. Please have a look at [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements)

Comment: It means that Maya documentation wrote know-nothing guys: http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2010help/CommandsPython/sphere.html

Comment: So it seems, and they're not even totally coherent in their use of whitespace. PEP8 is the official reference, and is very largely respected. Stick to it, and your good edit suggestions will be flawless ;)

Comment: Thanx, I've got it))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution for my problem:

```
def playBlast():
    for time in range(1, 201, 1):
        if nuke.frame(time) >= 1 and nuke.frame(time) <= 99:
            nuke.activeViewer().play(1)
        else: 
            nuke.activeViewer().stop() 

playBlast()
```